# Convert aggregrate to xml and then to SQL Server table types?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml

In my app, I have a method that calculate prices based on certain parameters. These parameters are properties on an entity. This entity is quite complex and it is made up of the root and 10+ child entities.

I was thinking of moving these calculations in a stored procedure. SO I though of the following steps:

1. Create table types that are the same as the tables where the aggregate is stored
2. The client deserializes the aggregate in XML and passes this XML as a parameter to the stored procedure
3. The stored procedure serializes the XML into the table types and works on these
4. The stored procedure returns an updated XML to the client

I know I can convert a table to/from XML, but can I convert a complete aggregate to/from XML?

Comment: if you want to pass xml to the procedure you don't even need a table type. you just need a temporary table or a table variable with the same structure as your base table. you could alternately pass the data as a data set into sql server using [TVP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)

Comment: yes you can but you have to be careful of the linking between tables (child entries).Any database can be made flat with all the columns of all the tables being joined in to a single table.  You then have a lot of null items and the total table memory size is becomes larger than the individual tables (due to the nulls).